# how to change image background via any file explorer

Tags: android, image, view, background

I am trying to understand how to change background image of an application (not via eclipse) using any file explorer in android(phone) and picking any file.png which will be saved as a background image in the app

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of (if I understand this correctly, you want to change the background of an application, via another application - right?) is to set the background to Theme.Wallpaper. Then in that other application, you can set the background differently and in the base application, the BG will be changed accordingly. Try this out and tell me you're after this.

Comment: well i dont understand what you really mean but i want to change background of my application in my application

Comment: That's what I meant. Asuming - pick the file explorer, navigate to the `.jpg`, `.png` etc. file and you set it to be your device's background. If your application uses `Theme.Wallpaper` as the default application Theme, then it will be changed, according to the background image you've set to the device.

Comment: well i understand what you mean...and i will have a try..but i dont promise nothinggg....:D:P

Comment: :-)) Don't worry, in case of a problem - say it here :)

Comment: Well, that doesn't help me much. What has failed, did you succeed of setting the Theme of the application to `Theme.Wallpaper`?

Comment: yes can you use a sample code to help me understand?

Comment: Check this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android . After tyou do what was mentioned there, when you set the wallaper of your phone/device, then this will be set too in your application.

Comment: is it possible to do it via intent?

Comment: I see absolutely no point of doing that? Why do you need an `Intent` to set the background of your application? I'm left with the impression, that you didn't understand my idea; if that's so, let me try one more time - 1. Problem - You want to change the background of your application (YApp for short), but you want to achieve this by choosing a picture from another application (let's say a Gallery). 2. Solution - the only thing I can think of is to set this desired image as a background to the device itself. Then in YApp you'll have `Theme.Wallpaper` set, which will use the device's background

Comment: Well, did that work? Should I put this as an answer?

Comment: yes.............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments above:

Well, the only thing I can think of (if I understand this correctly, you want to change the background of an application, via another application - right?) is to set the background to Theme.Wallpaper. Then in that other application, you can set the background differently and in the base application, the BG will be changed accordingly.

Asuming - pick the file explorer, navigate to the .jpg, .png etc. file and you set it to be your device's background. If your application uses `Theme.Wallpaper` as the default application Theme, then it will be changed, according to the background image you've set to the device.

In simpler terms:
1. Problem - You want to change the background of your application (YApp for short), but you want to achieve this by choosing a picture from another application (let's say a Gallery).
2. Solution - the only thing I can think of is to set this desired image as a background to the device itself. Then in YApp you'll have `Theme.Wallpaper` set, which will use the device's background

To put this with code, here's a sample extraction from the `AndroidManifest`:

`<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent">
</activity>`

This could be applied to any activity. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) the link for reference.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for your answer but you could use some code so as to be perfect! :))))))